# Quartz or OpenGL for a drawing app

Tags: ios, opengl-es, quartz-graphics

I have built a drawing app (free-drawing, placing lines, circles, polys, burning in text, etc) and have wondered whether I could have done this better than what I did, which was use Quartz for my drawing. Would it have been better to have used openGL? I'm really asking with completely no sense of why it would or wouldn't be better, but just knowing that a lot of apps simply use openGL for games and flashy apps versus the usual boring mail app.  Can someone spell out the advantages of either approach? My initial thinking was that I did not have the need for 3d rendering, so diving into the complexities of creating a GL app with all its draw states and trickiness (see, I don't even know what they are) was not worth the limited time I had to implement.

Answer (score 2):

Quartz is generally a much more pleasant API than OpenGL ES, especially for the types of things you are drawing.  If your app performs well with Quartz and you don't need the features of OpenGL ES, then there is no reason to consider using OpenGL ES.

Comment: Thanks, that's reassuring. One aspect I could use more detail on is whether generally GL has much better performance than quartz2d. It's not too practical for me to build it in GL just to compare performance. Is it even possible to make such a generalization as to whether GL is faster than Quartz for 2D drawing?

Comment: You really have to try it both ways to know.